# WARN Require cycle: src\Navigation\StackNavigation.js -> src\Navigation\TabsNavigation.js -> src\Navigation\StackNavigation.js

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation, react-navigation-stack, react-navigation-bottom-tab, android-bottomnav

WARN  Require cycle: src\Navigation\StackNavigation.js -> src\Navigation\TabsNavigation.js -> src\Navigation\StackNavigation.jsRequire cycles are allowed, but can result in uninitialized values. Consider refactoring to remove the need for a cycle.

I'm starting on react native and nesting navigators is quite a challenge to me. When the dashboard is displayed, the above warning is displayed.

When I try to navigate to ProductsStack, this error is displayed.
ERROR  Warning: Cannot update a component (`BottomTabNavigator`) while rendering a different component (`ProductsStack`). To locate the bad setState() call inside `ProductsStack`, follow the stack trace as described in https://reactjs.org/link/setstate-in-render

Below is my code:
**StackNavigation.js
**

```
`import React from 'react'
import { createStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/stack";
import Brands from '../Screens/Brands'
import Products2 from '../Screens/Products2'
import Warehouses from '../Screens/Warehouses'
import AdminProfile from '../Screens/AdminProfile'
import Products from '../Screens/Products'
import Purchases from '../Screens/Purchases'
import Sales from '../Screens/Sales'
import Expenses from '../Screens/Expenses'
import Accounting from '../Screens/Accounting'
import TabsNavigation from './TabsNavigation';
import More from '../Screens/More';
import Login from '../auth/Login'
import { getFocusedRouteNameFromRoute } from '@react-navigation/native';
import Categories2 from '../Screens/Categories2';


const Stack=createStackNavigator()
const tabHiddenRoutes = ["Categories","Brands","Products2","Warehouses","AdminProfile","Products","Purchases","Sales","Expenses","Accounting"];


const MainStack = () => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator 
    screenOptions={{headerShown:false}} initialRouteName='Dashboard2'>
    <Stack.Screen name='Dashboard2' component={TabsNavigation}/>
      </Stack.Navigator>
  )
}

const ProductsStack = ({navigation,route}) => {
if(tabHiddenRoutes.includes(getFocusedRouteNameFromRoute(route))){
  navigation.setOptions({tabBarStyle: {display: 'none'}});
 } else {
 navigation.setOptions({tabBarStyle: {display: 'flex'}});
}
    return (
      <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen name='Products3' component={Products} options={{headerShown:false}} />
      {/* <Stack.Screen name='Categories' component={Categories} /> */}
      <Stack.Screen name='Categories' component={Categories2} />
      <Stack.Screen name='Brands' component={Brands} />
      <Stack.Screen name='Products2' component={Products2}  options={{title:'Products'}}/>
      <Stack.Screen name='Warehouses' component={Warehouses} />
  
      </Stack.Navigator>
    )
  }
  const MoreStack = ({navigation,route}) => {
    if(tabHiddenRoutes.includes(getFocusedRouteNameFromRoute(route))){
      navigation.setOptions({tabBarStyle: {display: 'none'}});
     } else {
     navigation.setOptions({tabBarStyle: {display: 'flex'}});
    }
    return (
      <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen name='More2' component={More} options={{headerShown:false}}/>
      <Stack.Screen name='AdminProfile' component={AdminProfile} />
      <Stack.Screen name='Products' component={Products} />
      <Stack.Screen name='Purchases' component={Purchases} />
      <Stack.Screen name='Sales' component={Sales} />
      <Stack.Screen name='Expenses' component={Expenses} />
      <Stack.Screen name='Accounting' component={Accounting} />
  
      </Stack.Navigator>
    )
  }


export {MainStack,ProductsStack,MoreStack}`
```

**TabsNavigation.js
**

```
import { View, Text } from 'react-native'
import React from 'react'
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import Dashboard from '../Screens/Dashboard';
import POS from '../Screens/POS';
import Reports from '../Screens/Reports'
import Ionicons from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons'
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialCommunityIcons';  ;
import { Platform, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { MoreStack, ProductsStack } from './StackNavigation';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native'


const Tabs = createBottomTabNavigator();
const TabsNavigation = () => {
  const navigation=useNavigation()
  
  return (
    <Tabs.Navigator screenOptions={{headerShown:'false',
    tabBarStyle:{backgroundColor:'white',minHeight:60,fontSize:16,paddingBottom:10
    },
    tabBarInactiveTintColor:'grey',
    tabBarActiveTintColor:"#38BDF8"}}>
    <Tabs.Screen name='Dashboard' component={Dashboard} options={
      {headerShown:false,
        tabBarIcon:({color,size})=>(
         <Icon name='home' color={color} size={30} />
          
        )
      }
    }/>
    <Tabs.Screen name='Products' component={ProductsStack} options={{
      headerShown:false,
        tabBarIcon:({color,size})=>(
         <Icon name='microsoft-xbox-controller-view' color={color} size={30} />
          
        )
      }
    }/>
    <Tabs.Screen name='POS' component={POS} options={{
      tabBarStyle:{display:'none'},
          headerLeft: () => (
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {navigation.goBack()}}>
                <Ionicons name='arrow-back-outline' size={25} color={'black'} style={{marginLeft:10}}/>
              </TouchableOpacity>
              
            
          ),
        tabBarLabel: () => null,
        tabBarIcon:({color,size})=>{
          return(
            <View style={{
              top:Platform.OS=="ios" ? -10:-20,
              width:Platform.OS=="ios"?50:60,
              height:Platform.OS=="ios"?50:60,
              borderRadius:Platform.OS=="ios"?25:20,
              backgroundColor:"#38BDF8",
              alignItems:'center',
              justifyContent:'center',
              padding:5
              
            }}>
              <Icon name='point-of-sale' size={50} color={"white"}  />
            </View>
          )
        }
        
      }
    }/>
    <Tabs. Screen name='Reports' component={Reports} options={
      {
        tabBarIcon:({color,size})=>(
         <Icon name='chart-areaspline' color={color} size={30} />
          
        )
      }
    }/>
      <Tabs.Screen name='More' component={MoreStack} options={{
      headerShown:false,
        tabBarIcon:({color,size})=>(
         <Icon name='view-grid-plus' color={color} size={30} />
          
        )
      }
    }/>
  </Tabs.Navigator>
  )
}


export default TabsNavigation
```

I've removed the unused imports but still has the warning

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the require cycle error by writing my navigation in one file

```
    import { View,Platform, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native'
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native'
import { createStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/stack";
import { getFocusedRouteNameFromRoute } from '@react-navigation/native';
import Dashboard from '../Screens/Dashboard';
import POS from '../Screens/POS';
import Reports from '../Screens/Reports'
import Ionicons from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons'
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialCommunityIcons';  ;
import More from '../Screens/More';
import Brands from '../Screens/Brands'
import Products2 from '../Screens/Products2'
import Warehouses from '../Screens/Warehouses'
import AdminProfile from '../Screens/AdminProfile'
import Products from '../Screens/Products'
import Purchases from '../Screens/Purchases'
import Sales from '../Screens/Sales'
import Expenses from '../Screens/Expenses'
import Accounting from '../Screens/Accounting'
import Categories2 from '../Screens/Categories2';
import Login from '../auth/Login'
// import SignUp from '../auth/SignUp'


const Tabs = createBottomTabNavigator();
const Stack=createStackNavigator()
const tabHiddenRoutes = ["Categories","Brands","Products2","Warehouses","AdminProfile","Products","Purchases","Sales","Expenses","Accounting"];
const MainStack = () => {
    return (
      <Stack.Navigator 
      screenOptions={{headerShown:false}} initialRouteName='Login'>
      <Stack.Screen name='Login' component={Login}/>
      {/* <Stack.Screen name='SignUp' component={SignUp}/> */}
      <Stack.Screen name='Dashboard2' component={TabsNavigation}/>
        </Stack.Navigator>
    )
  }
  
  const ProductsStack = ({navigation,route}) => {
    useEffect(()=>{
      if(tabHiddenRoutes.includes(getFocusedRouteNameFromRoute(route))){
        navigation.setOptions({tabBarStyle: {display: 'none'}});
       } else {
       navigation.setOptions({tabBarStyle: {display: 'flex'}});
      }
    },[navigation,route])
  
      return (
        <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name='Products3' component={Products} options={{headerShown:false}} />
        <Stack.Screen name='Categories' component={Categories2} />
        <Stack.Screen name='Brands' component={Brands} />
        <Stack.Screen name='Products2' component={Products2}  options={{title:'Products'}}/>
        <Stack.Screen name='Warehouses' component={Warehouses} />
    
        </Stack.Navigator>
      )
    }
    const MoreStack = ({navigation,route}) => {
      useEffect(()=>{
        if(tabHiddenRoutes.includes(getFocusedRouteNameFromRoute(route))){
          navigation.setOptions({tabBarStyle: {display: 'none'}});
         } else {
         navigation.setOptions({tabBarStyle: {display: 'flex'}});
        }
      },[navigation,route])
      return (
        <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name='More2' component={More} options={{headerShown:false}}/>
        <Stack.Screen name='AdminProfile' component={AdminProfile} />
        <Stack.Screen name='Products' component={Products} />
        <Stack.Screen name='Purchases' component={Purchases} />
        <Stack.Screen name='Sales' component={Sales} />
        <Stack.Screen name='Expenses' component={Expenses} />
        <Stack.Screen name='Accounting' component={Accounting} />
    
        </Stack.Navigator>
      )
    }
const TabsNavigation = () => {
  const navigation=useNavigation()
  
  return (
    <Tabs.Navigator screenOptions={{headerShown:'false',
    tabBarStyle:{backgroundColor:'white',minHeight:60,fontSize:16,paddingBottom:10
    },
    tabBarInactiveTintColor:'grey',
    tabBarActiveTintColor:"#38BDF8"}}>
    <Tabs.Screen name='Dashboard' component={Dashboard} options={
      {headerShown:false,
        tabBarIcon:({color,size})=>(
         <Icon name='home' color={color} size={30} />
          
        )
      }
    }/>
    <Tabs.Screen name='Products' component={ProductsStack} options={{
      headerShown:false,
        tabBarIcon:({color,size})=>(
         <Icon name='microsoft-xbox-controller-view' color={color} size={30} />
          
        )
      }
    }/>
    <Tabs.Screen name='POS' component={POS} options={{
      tabBarStyle:{display:'none'},
          headerLeft: () => (
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {navigation.goBack()}}>
                <Ionicons name='arrow-back-outline' size={25} color={'black'} style={{marginLeft:10}}/>
              </TouchableOpacity>
              
            
          ),
        tabBarLabel: () => null,
        tabBarIcon:({color,size})=>{
          return(
            <View style={{
              top:Platform.OS=="ios" ? -10:-20,
              width:Platform.OS=="ios"?50:60,
              height:Platform.OS=="ios"?50:60,
              borderRadius:Platform.OS=="ios"?25:20,
              backgroundColor:"#38BDF8",
              alignItems:'center',
              justifyContent:'center',
              padding:5
              
            }}>
              <Icon name='point-of-sale' size={50} color={"white"}  />
            </View>
          )
        }
        
      }
    }/>
    <Tabs.Screen name='Reports' component={Reports} options={
      {
        tabBarIcon:({color,size})=>(
         <Icon name='chart-areaspline' color={color} size={30} />
          
        )
      }
    }/>
      <Tabs.Screen name='More' component={MoreStack} options={{
      headerShown:false,
        tabBarIcon:({color,size})=>(
         <Icon name='view-grid-plus' color={color} size={30} />
          
        )
      }
    }/>
  </Tabs.Navigator>
  )
}

  
  
  export {MainStack}
```

I also utilized the useEffect in ProductStack to get rid of the second warning

```
ERROR Warning: Cannot update a component (BottomTabNavigator)  
  while rendering a different component (ProductsStack).  
  To locate the bad setState() call inside ProductsStack,  
  follow the stack trace as described in https://reactjs.org/link/setstate- in-render
```